# java.io.StreamCorruptedException when serialize object with enum fields

Tags: java, android, serialization, enums

I use serialization to interconnect between my service and application in Android.
I get unstable exception `java.io.StreamCorruptedException`. Android 4.1.2, [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/ics-mr1-release/luni/src/main/java/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java) is ObjectInputStream.java, corresponding this version of Android.

```
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.corruptStream(ObjectInputStream.java:701)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readContent(ObjectInputStream.java:749)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.discardData(ObjectInputStream.java:662)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnumDescInternal(ObjectInputStream.java:1577)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnumDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1556)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:793)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2175)
... 18 more
```

Also LogCat says that problem appears when reading object of class GameServerData.java

**GameServerData.java:**

```
public class GameServerData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5912897328563239940L;

    public enum GameState {
        WAITING, PLAYING, FINISHED
    }

    public final int Id;
    public final String White;
    public final String Black;
    public final int WhiteRating;
    public final int BlackRating;
    public final boolean Rated;
    public final int Time;
    public final int Inc;
    public final String StartFen;    
    public String MainLine;

    public long WhiteClock;
    public long BlackClock;

    public PlayerColor Relation;
    public GameState Status;

    public int Countdown;
    public StopEvent StopEvent;
}
```

PlayerClock, StopEvent are simple Enums with simple enumeration, without complex fields.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Do you have the same version of the object code deployed at both ends?

Comment: Yes, there are in the same application

Comment: That doesn't answer my question in any way. You have described two separate elements of your application. Are they both using the same versions of the .class files?

Comment: I have two elements in my application - GUI and service. They are compiled within one application. Sorry, may be "GameServerData" is wrong name. Is is used only between service and GUI, not by server. So, answer for your question is "yes, they use the same version of .class files"

Comment: I've noticed, that before this error "!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!" message appears. So, when read object from data, data is corrupted by failed transaction.